# Battle Ship Winning Algorithm - Optimal Strategy

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, game-theory

I have an $8 \times 8$ grid. I have three ships that are $4$ long, $3$ long, and $2$ long. Is there an algorithm that can ensure a win every time? Oh! Most importantly, you must know the number of bombs I have: $24$ bombs

---

I don't know if a generalization would be fruitful, but it might prove interesting; that is, an $n\times n$ grid with $m$ ships of length(s) $k_1, k_2, k_3, \dots, k_m$ each of course being less than or equal to $n$, and a supply of $\beta$ bombs.

---

*n.b.* - By "Battle Ship" the OP means "one person dropping bombs on a grid with $m$ hidden ships, being oriented either horizontally or vertically within the grid, and having a supply of $\beta$ bombs."

Comment: I'm thinking some kind of "choice matrix" to decide what cell to choose based on historic picks where $0$ represents a no hit, and $1$ represents a hit. Unpicked cells can be another number I guess... Maybe $-1$ would work?

Comment: There is no algorithm that ensures that you win *every* time, but the might be an *optimal* strategy. The reason you cannot win everytime is that this is a game of chance, not perfect information. So your opponent can get lucky and hit every time.

Comment: Optimal strategy works. Is your comment based on probability?

Answer (score 0):

There is no winning strategy. Even for just the $2$-long boat alone, you would need 32 bombs to be sure.

Optimal strategies are also not possible here. You can make optimal strategies for when the opponen't boats are 'randomly' positioned (although even that is only a minor improvement), but a well-playing opponent will compensate that by putting their boats with a higher probability on less beneficial squares, making it a purely chance-based game.